# No module named 'tensorflow_probability'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I need to use Tensorflow and Tensorflow_Probability. After installing it by these commands: `conda install tensorflow-probability` or `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability` , I ran it in the notebook:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
```

but it returns this error:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-41494c8c96ff> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow_probability as tfp

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_probability'.
```

The results of

```
pip list
```

is as below (related parts):

```
tblib                              1.3.2
tensorboard                        1.13.1
tensorflow                         1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator               1.13.0
tensorflow-probability             0.7.0
termcolor                          1.1.0
terminado                          0.8.1
testpath                           0.4.2
tfp-nightly                        0.8.0.dev20190708
Theano                             1.0.4
toolz                              0.9.0
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem (I am using Win 10)?

Comment: on which enviorment are you loading it? the import command?

Comment: @PV8 I have "base" environment and also my defined environment  "TensorFlowEnv". The output of "pip list" seems to be from the defined environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your versions are correct and your command is correct too.

Seems like inconsistency in other module is causing this.

run the following commands and try again:

```
pip install -U dm-sonnet==1.23
pip install --upgrade tfp-nightly
```

References:
https://github.com/deepmind/graph_nets/issues/3
https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/103

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. The "sudo" is a Linux function and I used the windows version of the second command.

Comment: Note you also had two versions of TFP installed -- `tensorflow-probability` (stable, versioned) and `tfp-nightly` (built and released nightly, less stable). TFP nightly *may* work with TF stable (especially since TF just released 1.14 pretty recently), but in general if you're using `tfp-nightly` you should also be using `tf-nightly`

Comment: @Ham82 happy you could find a solution!

Answer (score 5):

tensorflow-probability             0.7.0
is not compatible with:
tensorflow                         1.13.1
check the tensoflow-probability version release page https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/releases

Correct solution will be either to upgrade tensorflow to 1.14.0 or downgrade tensorflow-probability to 0.6.0

```
pip install -U tensorflow-probability==0.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer, you have to find a version compatible with your TensorFlow version through this page: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/releases